# SELECT Count from mysql to Google Geo Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I've been trying to retrieve data from mysql database using `SELECT Count`, as I got a list of countries which I want to count how many times each country is displayed in the column `SovereignState`, to a [Google Geo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) and by browsing around, I believe that `json_encode` should do the trick.

However, I have no idea how to get make a `json_encode` from my php code and then put it in the `DataTable` of the chart.

This is the php code:

```
define('DB_NAME', '');
    define('DB_USER', '');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','');
    define('DB_HOST', '');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) ;

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die ('Could not connect: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT SovereignState, COUNT(*) FROM Data_2 GROUP BY SovereignState";
    echo $sql;
    //$result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $conn->multi_query($sql);

    if(!$result) {
        echo "Could not successdully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error(); exit;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    do {
        if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s - %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }           
    } while ($conn->more_results());
    echo "</pre>";

    $conn->close();
```

And this is the html code of the google geochart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

        function drawRegionsMap() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Country', 'Number'],
                   ]);

            var options = {};
            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode()` from your PHP code and use Ajax in order to get the JSON into your JS code.

Also, (not recommended) you can just call a PHP function from your JS code with `<?php myFunction();?>`, that function should return an `echo json_encode()`.